# Conway's Game of Life having logic issues

Tags: ruby, conways-game-of-life

I'm working on Conway's Game of Life. I have some logic issue that  it always finishes in 2 or 3 ticks (usually only 2). Most of the time, it is with all cells dead, but occasionally it will have a 1 or 2 still alive. I can't find what part is causing the behavior of the second tick being almost entirely, if not completely, dead.

Do any of you see any major issues that might be causing this behavior?

```
require 'pry'
class Game
  def initialize(size)
    @size = size
    @ticks = 1
    @current_board = Array.new(size) { Array.new(size) { (rand(99) % 5 == 0) ? false : true } }
    @future_board = Array.new(size) { Array.new(size) }
    # @future_board = @current_board
  end

  def is_alive?(y, x)
    if @current_board[y]
      @current_board[y][x]
    end
  end

  def check_neigbors(y, x)
    neighbors = {
      top:          [y-1, x],
      top_right:    [y-1, x+1],
      right:        [y, x+1],
      bottom_right: [y+1, x+1],
      bottom:       [y+1, x],
      bottom_left:  [y+1, x-1],
      left:         [y, x-1],
      top_left:     [y-1, x-1]
    }
    neighbor_state = {
      top:          false,
      top_right:    false,
      right:        false,
      bottom_right: false,
      bottom:       false,
      bottom_left:  false,
      left:         false,
      top_left:     false
    }
    # binding.pry
    neighbors.each { |k, v| neighbor_state[k] = true if is_alive?(v[0], v[1]) }
    live_neighbor_count = 0
    neighbor_state.each_value { |v| live_neighbor_count += 1 if v }
    live_neighbor_count
  end

  def cell_lives(y, x)
    @future_board[y][x] = true
  end

  def cell_dies(y, x)
    @future_board[y][x] = false
  end

  def display_board
    # need to display board here
    system("clear")
    # @current_board.each do
    # |r| puts r.map { |c| c ? 'O' : 'X' }.join(" ")
    # |r| puts r.map { |c| c }.join(" ")
    puts @current_board.map { |row| row.map { |cell| cell ? 'X' : ' ' }.inspect }
    # end
    puts "\nTicks: #{@ticks}"
  end

  def play
    loop do
      display_board
      @current_board.each do |r| # outer loop to iterate through rows
        row_index = @current_board.index(r).to_i
        r.each do |c| # inner loop to iterate through columns
          column_index = r.index(c).to_i
          live_neighbor_count = check_neigbors(row_index, column_index) # count the number of live neighbors
          cell_dies(row_index, column_index) if ( is_alive?(row_index, column_index) ) && live_neighbor_count < 2 # rule 1
          cell_lives(row_index, column_index) if ( is_alive?(row_index, column_index) ) && ( live_neighbor_count == 2 || live_neighbor_count == 3 ) # rule 2
          cell_dies(row_index, column_index) if ( is_alive?(row_index, column_index) ) && live_neighbor_count > 3 # rule 3
          cell_lives(row_index, column_index) if !( is_alive?(row_index, column_index) ) && live_neighbor_count == 3 # rule 4

        end
      end
      if @current_board == @future_board # board is gridlocked. Game over!
        puts "\nGAME OVER!"
        exit!
      else
        @current_board = @future_board # update the board
        @ticks += 1
        sleep(1)
      end
    end
  end
end

print "How large of a grid do you want: "
grid_size = gets.to_i
game = Game.new grid_size
game.play
```

Comment: no ruby expert, but pretty sure  @ current_board = @ future_board    makes them both point to the same data structure, what you want to do is COPY the futureboard onto the current board

Comment: This is more of a code review. The ruby community has settled for using 2 spaces instead of tabs. Please try and do this in your own code. It makes it easier for Ruby devs to read. Incorrect indentation could lead to issues. Because ruby allows for `?` in method names, there is no need to prefix a predicate method with `is_`. Your `is_alive?` method can be called `alive?`. Predicate methods should **ALWAYS** return only `true` or `false`. Currently, your `alive?` method can return `nil`. You can shorten it to `def alive?(y,x); !!@current_board[y][x]; end`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Could you explain the `!!@current_board[y][x]` piece? Maybe I'm missing something, but the reason for the first check of @current_board[y] is because when checking neighbors, it was causing the game to crash. When the neighbor check set y+1 on the last row, is_alive? was called with a non-existent row and crashing out. Does your snippet account for that?

Comment: A `!` will negate the current value. Using `!!` will do a double negation. This is the generally accepted way to turn 'truthy' values, like `nil`, into actual boolean values. This will work even when there are no items in the requested index. doing `arr[50][50]` will return `nil`, assuming there is nothing at that index (as long as the array is at least two deep). So `!!nil == false`. It just guarantees that you will always return either `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Conway's game of life, if you start with a random arrangement of cells, most of them do die on the second tick just because of the rules of the game, so I have no evidence there is a bug.

How about you make a glider or something and make sure it behaves as expected?  If it doesn't work, then please post the output of your program and point out the first frame where the output is wrong, and post what you would expect the output to be.

Comment: Not sure why my random generated cells were not working well and other's were working just fine. Not sure if it was even the issue. Manually pre-setting to one of the many designs out there caused the game of life to work properly. This was the closest correct answer. Thanks guys.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  If most of your randomly-generated cells die off on the first round, that's probably "working".

Answer (score 0):

try :-

```
 @current_board = @futureboard.dup
```

Comment: if you guys are referring to at the bottom where it updates the board, trying .dup and .clone produce the same result as not having either of them. Didn't work. Thanks, and keep 'em coming.